# How to send email [csv format] in my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, email

I am generating a report in my app. Now I want to send this report as an email.

I have seen :

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MailComposer/

link for help.

I want to format whole the text & image & then it should be sent.
I have complete data in an array. Now how to generate csv from that & how to send it as an email?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got 1 solution :

[[array componentsJoinedByString:@","] writeToFile:@"components.csv" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];